# Why does increasing font size in a makebox, fill it into my above vertical space?

Tags: spacing, boxes

I am learning how to use boxes to lay out blocks of text.

I am putting a `\makebox` and `\minipage` together. It looks great in example one. But when I increase the font size in the makebox using `\Large` in example two, the text moves **up** into the `\vspace`. Can someone please help me understand what is going on and how to fix it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\vspace{5mm}
\hrule
\vspace{2mm}
\noindent\makebox[1.7cm][l]{\textbf{50.12}}
\minipage[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1.7cm\relax}
 Here is just some more text. It is for testing stuff. I wonder if this will work. Here is some more textm it is about enough now.
\endminipage

\vspace{5mm}
\hrule
\vspace{2mm}
\noindent\makebox[1.7cm][l]{\textbf{\Large 50.12}}
\minipage[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1.7cm\relax}
 Here is just some more text. It is for testing stuff. I wonder if this will work. Here is some more textm it is about enough now.
\endminipage

\end{document}
```

Comment: TeX  aligns the baseline with the first baseline of the minipage. Don't use the [t] option in the minipage, if you want it centered. Btw: Better use \begin{minipage}/\end{minipage} instead of \minipage. The second doesn't add groups.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this stuff is going into a macro, so i needed to split out the `\endminipage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this is not the cause of the issue, *never* use `\minipage` and `\endminipage` inside the `document` environment. Always use the `\begin` and `\end` syntax for your environments. The `\foo` and `\endfoo` syntax may be used when defining new environments.

TeX aligns the reference points of the boxes; the reference point of the box containing the number is its baseline and the one for the `minipage` is the baseline of the top line (because of `[t]`). You need to lower the number, but also to make it have zero depth.

What you probably want is to align the top of the number with the top of the text, but you have to ensure the text runs over at least two lines. With some more work this limitation can be raised, if needed. Find a better name than `foo`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newenvironment{foo}[1]
 {%
  \par\addvspace{5mm}%
  \hrule
  \nopagebreak\vspace{2mm}%
  \noindent\vphantom{T}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`T-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[1.7cm][l]{\Large#1}}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1.7cm\relax}%
 }{%
  \end{minipage}\par\addvspace{5mm}%
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}{50.12}
Here is just some more text. It is for testing stuff. I wonder if this
will work. Here is some more textm it is about enough now.
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you might be specific that `\begin{minipage} ... \end{minipage}` is the correct user syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As Ulrike mentioned, Tex wants to align things on the basis of their baselines, rather than their upper extent.

One way you could get literal top alignment of two boxes of different font size is to use the `\belowbaseline` macro of the `stackengine` package to set the top of both the `\makebox` as well as the `\minipage` a fixed distance below the baseline, in this case a distance of `-\ht\strutbox`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine}

\begin{document}

\vspace{5mm}
\hrule
\vspace{2mm}
\noindent\makebox[1.7cm][l]{\textbf{50.12}}
\minipage[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1.7cm\relax}
 Here is just some more text. It is for testing stuff. I wonder if this will work. Here is some more textm it is about enough now.
\endminipage

\vspace{5mm}
\hrule
\vspace{2mm}
\noindent\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\makebox[1.7cm][l]{\textbf{\Large 50.12}}}
\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\minipage[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1.7cm\relax}
 Here is just some more text. It is for testing stuff. I wonder if this will work. Here is some more textm it is about enough now.
\endminipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is another working solution. Im still learning latex myself—I wonder why we would want to do this using the `stackengine` package? The code doesn't seem simpler to me.

Comment: @Jacob As the author of `stackengine`, I have been known to say that if the only tool in your toolbox is a hammer, pretty soon every problem starts to look like a nail.  Also, while I didn't do it here, the syntax could all be wrapped up inside a macro.

Comment: That makes sense then. I hope you didn't take my post the wrong way. Im just trying to learn all the basic basic commands so I can start understanding how macro's work, so I am trying to get back to basics.

Comment: @Jacob No problem at all.  It is something of a joke around here with the regulars that, when in doubt, Steven will stack-it out.